# why this sql query inserting garbage value in the database instead of the number value [POST method]

Tags: php, mysql

I am working on this form but it's stroing garbage value of the 'phone' field in the database where I am giving the right number. what's wrong in the code? First i set the length of that field to 11 and thought that could be the problem. but when I increased that to even 50 the same problem occurred again. How to solve this?

PS: neglect the security part of the form, it's just for testing purpose.

```
<table border="1" id="tab1">
<form action="create.php" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">

    <tr align='center'><td>Ad Title:</td><td><input type='text' name='ad_title' id="ad_title" placeholder='type ad title'/></td></tr>
    <tr align='center'><td>Ad Description:</td><td><textarea name='ad_details' id="ad_details" placeholder='type ad details' cols="40" rows="10"></textarea></td></tr>
    <tr align="center"></tr>
    <tr align="center"><td>Category:</td><td>
        <select name="category">
            <option value="mobile">Mobile Phone</option>
            <option value="computer">Computer</option>
            <option value="book">Books</option>
            <option value="fashion">Fashion and Beauty</option>
        </select>
    </td></tr>
    <tr align='center'><td>Phone Number:</td><td><input type='number' id="phone" name='phone' placeholder='type your Phone Number'/></td></tr>

    <tr align='center'><td>Email:</td><td><input type='text' name='email' id="email" placeholder='type your email'/></td></tr>

    <tr align='center'><td>Price:</td><td><input type='text' name='price' id="price" placeholder='enter your desired Price'/></td></tr>

    <tr align="center"><td>Negotiable:</td><td><input type="radio" name="nego" value="yes"/>YES<input type="radio" name="nego" value="no"/>NO</td></tr>

    <tr align="center"><td>City/Town:</td><td>
        <select name="city">
            <option value="Jalpaiguri">Jalpaiguri</option>
            <option value="Siliguri">Siliguri</option>
        </select>
    </td></tr>

    <tr align='center'><td>Location:</td><td><input type='text'  id="location" name='location' placeholder='type your Location'/></td></tr>
    <tr><td>Choose Photo for Ad:</td><td><input type='file' name='ad_pic'/></td></tr>
    <tr align='center'><td colspan="7"><input type='submit' id="submit" name ='submit' value='Create Ad'/></td></tr>
</form>
</table>
```

the php code is as follows:

```
<?php

session_start();

if(!isset($_SESSION['username'])){
    header("location:login.php");
}

$user  = $_SESSION['username'];

$conn = new mysqli("localhost","root","","pending");

    if($conn->connect_error){
        echo "<script>document.getElementById('noti').innerHTML='Database Error.Please Try again !';</script>";
    }

if(isset($_POST['submit'])){

    $ad_title = $_POST["ad_title"];
    $ad_details = $_POST["ad_details"];
    $category = $_POST["category"];
    $phone = $_POST["phone"];
    $email = $_POST["email"];
    $nego = $_POST["nego"];
    $city = $_POST["city"];
    $location = $_POST["location"];
    $price = $_POST["price"];

$sql = $conn->query("INSERT INTO ads(ad_id,user_name,ad_title,ad_details,price,category,phone,email,negotiable,city,location) VALUES('','$user','$ad_title','$ad_details','$price','$category','$phone','$email','$nego','$city','$location')");

$pid = $conn->insert_id;

$newname = "$pid.jpg";

move_uploaded_file($_FILES['ad_pic']['tmp_name'], "ad_images/$newname");
}
```

?>

Comment: let me gues you made phone an int?

Comment: yes I made it int sir

Comment: change it to a varchar- that will solve the issue

Comment: here is the screenshot of the database stored value 

http://s11.postimg.org/nicj4i0yr/Screenshot_1.png

Comment: Thanks sir.. it worked.. :)

can you say why int did not work? when should I use VARCHAR and when INT?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem is with your *Insert Query*.

in your `phone` database field you given `type` as `INT`. And in your query you are trying to insert as a string `'$phone'`.

Correct way is, You should use just `$phone`.

### **Explaining Why**

**Why this statement is wrong in your case.(`'$phone'` and `$phone`)**

- Anything between single-quotes is considered a string, not a number. When you say `'500'`, MySQL **reads that as three characters of text**, but when you say `500`, MySQL **reads that as a single number**.
- The BETWEEN ... AND operators are meant to check if a value is in between a range of numbers (dates are also considered numbers internally). Trying to use it on strings will not work properly.
- This is a **big mistake**, by the way. A huge waste of space. When you store an integer as a VARCHAR, the storage requirements for each letter in the number is equal to the total storage requirements if it were stored as an INT.

**So your Query should come as**

```
$sql = $conn->query("INSERT INTO ads(ad_id,user_name,ad_title,ad_details,price,category,phone,email,negotiable,city,location) VALUES('','$user','$ad_title','$ad_details','$price','$category',$phone,'$email','$nego','$city','$location')");
```

*To Get easy idea*

change this to `'$phone'` this `$phone`

[Difference between `varchar` and `int`](http://bytes.com/topic/mysql/answers/884673-difference-between-varchar-int#post3558291)

Comment: Learn Right thing Friend. Happy to help :)

Comment: somewhat correct- however: phone numbers should be stored as varchar not int, as they may have leading zeroes. and as he's taking the data raw from what the use types in they could have space hyphens + etc.